# robots.txt in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, robots.txt

I just was wondering if the robots.txt file is supposed to work like general robots txt files. So, you type for example "disallow/admin/*" place it into the the root Laravel folder and that's it.

Is it like this ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Remember, that website address is relevant to public dir. So, 
if you want **robots.txt** to work in **Laravel**, it must be placed in the `public` folder.

Comment: Bruh, is it ok to let it being accessable from the site/browser?

Comment: yes. robots.txt should be public

Comment: There is a robots.txt file in the public folder by default

Answer (score 0):

robots.txt is a special file used by search bots to read and crawl the website resources.

robots.txt should be at the root of the website.

The root directory differs from OS to OS. I am giving a few of them. Better that you consult with your server admin.

Example:

```
/public_html
/htdocs
/html
```

Comment: The OP asked about robots.txt specifically in a Laravel application.  Your answer does not address the OP's question in any relative or meaningful way as the OP didn't ask WHAT a robots.txt file is, nor did the OP ask where you would place a traditional robots.txt file.  In a Laravel app, the web entry point is at /public in the index.php file as pointed out by Michal G above.